# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/template-parts/single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In my blog site everything is working fine but on some posts images are not coming in the image src i am getting this error:

```
<img class="lazy _single__img" alt="" data-src="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in <b>/var/www/fisharoma/wp-content/themes/wisledge2/template-parts/single.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
" src="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in <b>/var/www/fisharoma/wp-content/themes/wisledge2/template-parts/single.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
">
```

According to the error something is wrong in my single.php line 20, but i can't figure out what am doing wrong.

Here is my single.php

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
if (empty($categories) || !count($categories)) {
    return;
}
$term = $categories[0];
?>
<article id="entry-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('_single'); ?>>
    <nav class="_path">
        <a class="_path__link" href="https://fisharoma.com/">Home &gt;</a>
        <a class="_path__link" href="<?php echo get_category_link($term->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $term->cat_name; ?> <?php _e('', 'wisledge'); ?></a>
        
    </nav>
    <?php the_title('<h1 class="_single__title">', '</h1>'); ?>
    <?php // the_post_thumbnail('large', ['class' => '_single__img']); ?>
    <img
        class="lazy _single__img"
        alt="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>"
        data-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large')[0]; ?>"
        src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large')[0]; ?>"
    />
    <div class="_single__content">
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/share'); ?>
        <div class="_meta">
            <span class="_meta__by"><?php _e('By ', 'wisledge'); ?></span>
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" class="_meta__author"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
            <?php if (get_the_time() != get_the_modified_time()) :?>
                <span class="_meta__updated"><?php _e('Updated', 'wisledge'); ?></span>
                <?php
                /*
                <!-- <time class="_meta__time" datetime="<?php the_modified_time('c'); ?>"><?php the_modified_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time> -->
                */
                ?>
                <time class="_meta__time"><?php the_modified_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/#return) returns false if there is no image available, and you're trying to access it using `[0]`. Your image is not available; you need to check the result before attempting access.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your image with a check condition first:

```
if(wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large')){
?>
<img
    class="lazy _single__img"
    alt="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>"
    data-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large')[0]; ?>"
    src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large')[0]; ?>"
/>
<?php
}
```